Batch zip multiple subfolders in separate folders
I’m trying to batch zip multiple subfolders inside separate folders.
For Example:
01\Folder01
02\Folder02

The following code works; however, it initially outputs with a winrar diagnostic error message twice where I click "cancel" and then proceeds to create the two individual zip files within both parent folders called Folder01.zip inside 01 and Folder02.zip inside 02.
How to do I edit this code so that winrar doesn’t prompt with the following error message for each subfolder: P:\Files\00\01.zip: No files to add and P:\Files\00\02.zip: No files to add
BTW, I’m running this batch file within a folder named: 00
Here is my code:
for /d /r %%f in (*) do (
  pushd %%f  
  "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRar.exe" a "%%f.zip"
  popd  
)
pause


It needs to create the zipped files individually inside folders 01 and 02 using the names of the subfolders inside those folders, eg. (Folder01 and Folder02).
My code cannot specify folder names because this is just a template for when there are many more folders with subfolders to zip.
This is how the structure should be after running the batch file from root-folder 00:
00\01\Folder01
00\01\Folder01.zip

00\02\Folder02
00\02\Folder02.zip


I noticed that you didn't specify the folder to add in your command so he probably tries to add everything in the current folder or nothing. You specify:
winrar a zipname FolderOrFilesToAdd
Something like that
Here is an example batch:
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do "C:\Program Files\winrar\winrar.exe" a -ep1 -r -inul "%%a.zip" "%%a\"

-inul = disable all messages...

The example command uses the argument -inul, but the description below it uses -inull. I'm guessing one is a typo.

@Chester Gillon thank you it is -inul
